# is possible to build a warehouse application using Oracle Application Express oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm intermediate **PHP** ,**MySQL** developer,currently, I'm building a warehouse application using **MySQL** with **InnoDB** engine and using **PHP**,I notice it's too annoying and slow to handle many languages at the same time(PHP,MySQL,HTML,CSS),then after googling I found (**Oracle Application Express**),it's sounds nice to me that I build my application and focusing on one programming language Oracle and leave the forms etc to the  **Oracle Application Express**.so is it possible to build a warehouse management system with **Oracle Application Express** and **Oracle 11g** ? I'm good with SQL and I can learn Oracle very fast,please guys share you experience with me.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: is that mean I can create login page so many users can use the system ,and also update the products and see the user that updated the record ?

Comment: You can create everything you want. For example, I saw internet-banking system, written on APEX.

Comment: @Dmitry thank, that's sounds very promising ,I can save time focusing on Oracle & PL/SQL instead on focusing on (PHP,MySQL,HTML,CSS,Javascript). in other word more productivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access pl sql from apex applications and apex itself generate a web frontend. 
yes you can also create a login page and the separate pages cann be secured by user specific access rights